# Value Provider Path null issue GXT 3.0

Tags: java, gwt, nullpointerexception, gxt, value-provider

In GXT 3.0, valueProvider, I have a null pointer exception issue.
I have this code snippet,

```
@Path("xxx.yyy")
ValueProvider<User, String> zzz();
```

I use a ValueProvider like this, and in this situation, if xxx or yyy is null, I simply got null pointer exception. In my implementation, yyy or xxx could be null but, I want that, if it's null, simply just don't show it or show it empty.

I use this ValueProviders almost everywhere in my implementation, so I need to find a wise solution in order not to make my code sphagetti.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think your problem is your path. GXT will create the following code from your annotation: getXxx().getYyy(). If getXxx() is null a NPE will occur, because GXT tries to get the value of getYyy().

Comment: But when NPE occurs build failed. I want that if it's null, just let it be something like empty String. Let me keep on process I mean.

Comment: You can add a fake getter `getzzz()` which returns exactly what you want. Then, your path will be `@Path("zzz")`

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 solutions :

- You can add a fake getter `getZzz()` on your object and make it return exactly what you want to display:
- You can give the implementation of the ValueProvider.

Example:

```
ValueProvider<User, String> zzz = new ValueProvider<User, String>() {

  @Override
  public String getValue(User user) {
    if(user.getXxx() == null | user.getXxx().getYyy() == null) {
      return "";
    }
    return object.getXxx().getYyy();
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue(User object, String value) {}

  @Override
  public String getPath() {
    return "xxx.yyy";
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course I could think this solution, but I needed wiser one, as I said in question, if I would use this implementation, my code would become sphagetti. I have nearly 90 path implementations like this.
My supervisor has edited the Sencha's library and we get rid of the problem. Thanks for all.